# Cannot lookup domain objects using WMI when connected to remote server

Tags: windows-server-2008, wmi

I have a VBscript on server10 that takes a parameter of a server name, connects to the server name and queries WMI for information about members of groups.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

Using the objWMIService object, I execute a query using strings such as

```
select SID from Win32_UserAccount where Domain='myDomain' and Name='npatnaik'
select SID from Win32_Group where Domain='myDomain' and Name='someGroup'
```

If I run the VBscript on server10, and pass the parameter server10 so that the get an instance of"winmgmts:\server10\root\cimv2", the query returns results and I am able to get the SID values of the Active Directory users and groups in the domain myDomain.
However, if I ran the script on server10, and pass it server11 as the parameter such that I get an instance of "winmgmts:\server11\root\cimv2", I am not able to get results for the Active Directory objects.

I am an administrator on server10 and server11, and both the servers are in the same domain. Both servers are  64 bit Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition SP2 (Build 6002)

I do not have a problem running the script on server10, connecting to server11 and getting information on the local users and groups on server11.
When I enumerate the members of groups on server11 and then try to get the SIDs of the members that happen to be users and groups from an Active Directory domain, that part does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall and allow remote management from Server manager (check box on the right).